# Excel VBA Database connection error: Cannot open database '(unknown)'

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access-2010, ado

I am trying to connect to Access Database using ADO DSN.

```
StrPath = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("DB_location")
strCon = "DSN=MS Access Database;DBQ=" & StrPath & ";"

Set con = New ADODB.Connection
con.Open strCon
```

I can connect to DB without any problem on my machine. However, when I tried running this exact macro on another PC, I ran into this issue on the last line:

[image]

I assumed it was due to Database Engine, but installing "Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable" from Microsoft's website didn't solve this problem. All the necessary references in VBA editor are present. 
There is no problem with DB or the macro, as I checked on a different PC, but this specific computer runs into this problem.

Comment: Can you check the `StrPath` variable? Be sure it is a full path and the PC can connect to it.

Comment: It is a full path. This macro works on any machine, but one. I suspect it might have to do with the Access Driver, but can't exactly figure it out, as I already installed the aforementioned driver.

Answer (score 0):

Changing

`strCon = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = " & StrPath & ";"`

solved this problem, which means the problem was somehow due to DSN. Does anyone have a guess about where does this problem might come from?

Comment: I think that when you specify a DSN, it must be present on the machine. Your change created a DSN-less  connection.

Comment: Do you know how can I check this, and if it is missing, how can I install it? I assumed downloading "Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable" will be sufficient.

Comment: This is worth a question by itself. There are *file* DSNs (in a file), *machine* and *user* DSNs, which go into registry.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and it ended up being my primary keys.  WHen i fixed my primary keys in the table it worked like a charm.